# How do I get a SharePoint table to link to access with proper column types through VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint, linked-list

I have a several sharepoint tables, some of which use lookup fields (I know I know they are bad but for this database we need the lookup fields to be in place).

If I manually link the table via the top ribbon it imports the table fine.

If i use VBA and DoCmd.TransferSharePointList acLinkSharePointList then it returns all lookup columns as "Short Text" instead of a lookup field.

I don't understand why it works perfectly when done manually but messes up when done through VBA. Anyone have any ideas? I can't find anyone with a similar issue on google.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

You want to put "False" in the "GetLookupDisplayValues" criteria shown in the link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb238962(v=office.12)

Comment: Is it 2007 only relevant? Then you should mention that in your question header for future readers.

Comment: I'm on Access 2016